# I can't connect to the web socket in django

Tags: django, websocket

I can't connect to the web socket in django.

This is asgi.py

```py
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import api.routing
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter, get_default_application
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "back.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                api.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        )
    )
})
```

This is routing.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('socket-server', consumers.Consumers.as_asgi())
]
```

This is consumers.py

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

class Consumers(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type': 'connection_established',
            'message': 'You are now connected!'
        }))

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

This is settings.py

```py
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "channels",
    "api",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'back.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

I tried to connect the web socket through postman after writing the code in django as follows. However, a **404 not found** error appears. I sent the request to *ws://localhost:8000/socket-server* url. What's the problem?

- python : 3.7.16
- channels : 3.0.5